# SpringXD limitations?

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I'm evaluating SpringXD and I am wondering if there are any limitations with the current functionality it provides. I couldn't find any documentation on this and I'm sure the answer falls under the "it depends" category, but thought I would ask anyways.

Examples of what I mean by this are:

- Is there a max limit on the number of streams that can be created? (I'm guessing not as these seem to be backed by a database but the answer may depend on what the streams are doing)
- Is there a max limit on the number of named channels that can be created? (I'm guessing this may depend on the underlying MOM used for message passing)
- Is there a max limit on the number of nodes (xd-node or xd-admin) that can be running in a system? (I'm guessing that this depends on zookeeper and on how many connections the underlying MOM allows)
- etc.

So generally speaking, are there any limitations of potential use cases that people should be aware of before picking up SpringXD?

Thank you,
Aaron

**EDIT from answer by @dturanski**

The situation I'm thinking of is having a potentially large number of streams (technically unbounded). I'm talking a minimum of maybe a couple thousand in the beginning to potentially half a million (or even more) if all goes well. Many of these streams would be working together over named channels that would also technically be unbounded. I'm not sure how SpringXD manages the creation of underlying destinations but i could see that there would be a problem having lots of topics/queues in a message broker depending on the underlying MOM technology used . Also, assume I would be able to scale the number of XD Nodes in the system to accommodate the load (thus the question on zookeeper limitations) and am able to deal with other infrastructure concerns. These streams wouldn't necessarily be performing a heavy workload. Question is specifically about the technological capabilities of the systems used by SpringXD.

So ignoring the practical limitations of having resources, am i way out fo my mind thinking that this is a capability of SpringXD?

Answer (score 0):

In theory there are no such limitations. There are practical limitations as you suggest, just as with any distributed system, and entirely dependent on system resources and work load. If you have a specific use case in mind that you think might push these limits, it would provide a context to address these questions.

Comment: i modified my question to respond to your answer.